# Developments of Riemannian geometry in recent decades.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, math-history

I have  very little knowledge about Ricci flow and Riemannian Geometry. I can't understand the evolution from the traditional Riemannian geometry to Ricci flow (or geometrical analysis ). Obviously, they  look quite different.

In the 1970s and before, seemly, most paper of Riemannian geometry are delicate and short. And the method has not universality in my view.

But now, the paper become  complex and long.  But they have similar frame, tool and way of thinking . For example, in mean curvature flow and Ricci flow, many same question is studied.

Seemly, the era has changed from division to unity (I'm not sure if I was imagining it).  Who can tell me the history of Riemannian geometry  in recent decades?  One hand, I want to know the story. On the other hand, I want to find a research direction which suitable for me. In fact, now, give me a paper, I cannot discern the magnitude of its significance. Therefore, I don't know which direction is potentially significant.

Comment: You might get better answers for this on Mathoverflow, maybe with some reframing, e.g., "what are current trends in Riemannian Geometry, and are there any recent survey papers on this?" or something like that. Maybe try the arXiv as well.

Comment: @DerekAllums  Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: The question is way too broad and based on, as you said, limited knowledge of the subject. And asking for research directions is off-topic also, you need an advisor for that. 
 However, it is definitely true that since 1970s, geometric analysis plays increasingly large role in RG. This is totally natural.

Comment: Before the work of people such as Aubin, Schoen, Yau, Hamilton, the most common approach was comparison geometry. The book by Cheeger and Ebin illustrates this very well. After that the use of nonlinear PDE theory, mostly elliptic,  became dominant. Some early major results involved minimal surfaces and also the Yamabe problem. Then Hamilton’s Ricci flow dropped like a bomb from the sky. This and the mean curvature flow became a major part of geometric analysis (this is a relatively recent term). After Perelman, it has become the dominant tool in the area.

Comment: Schoen and Yau have lecture notes that focus on the elliptic theory.

Comment: @Deane  You are great. I think I'm overthinking it. I should accumulate enough knowledge and start with a specific problem. Thanks.